# My ajax site is not being indexed by google, even though our meta tags make sense

Tags: ajax, indexing, tags, meta

Our site is [www.recordfarm.com](http://www.recordfarm.com) and it runs on ajax. Even though we have the proper meta tags, google won't index any of the pages. Shouldn't the pages get indexed since the meta tag info is in HTML?

When we submit our site map to Google Webmaster, it only crawls the site (33,000 URLS) but does not index it. The site has a lot of users, but we are not sure why it is not indexing in google properly.

Comment: by "not being indexed", do you mean there is zero on the index status tab on webmaster tools?

Comment: In GWT you can use "fetch as googlebot" - I would look there to see for any hints.

Comment: @robasta Only the homepage for the korean version of the site is indexed (www.recordfarm.co.kr). No other page is indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

1. Go in your index file
2. Insert there all your website links like this:

`<a style="display:none;" href="www.mysite.com/page1.php alt="Page title">Link</a>
<a style="display:none;" href="www.mysite.com/page2.php alt="Page title">Link</a>
<a style="display:none;" href="www.mysite.com/page3.php alt="Page title">Link</a>
<a style="display:none;" href="www.mysite.com/page4.php alt="Page title">Link</a>`

You can insert those links in your index page, after the  tag. The principle is simple: google bots will see and crawl those simple links but your visitors won't see those links because are hidden with display:none attribute. I think your page don't get crawled because you're on ajax, I had this problem. But I also think that my answer will fix your problem.

Comment: Is this feasible if my site has 33,000 links? Won't putting them all on the index page create slow load times for visitors? Even if I submit a single link (not the homepage) to google webmaster, it doesn't get indexed.